# Type constructor aliases without "polluting" a module

Tags: types, module, ocaml

I'd like to define a type alias for constructors to be reused in a given module, without having to prefix them by the path to the module where they're defined. I'd also like to avoid "polluting" the latter module by doing an `open`/`include` that would import too many definitions.

Here's an example of what I'd like (which does not compile):

```
module A = struct
  type t = Red | Blue
end

module B = struct
  type t = A.t
  let f = function
    | Red -> 1  (*Error: Unbound constructor Red*)
    | Blue -> 0
  let
end
```

Doing `include A` or `open A` inside B would both work here (`Red` and `Blue` would be valid), but both will add definitions to B, "polluting" it.

`open` will do the least amount of damage, but still allows mistakes to be made, e.g. if `A` defines a symbol that is accidentally used in `B` due to the `open`, I won't have a compilation error.

Is there a way to avoid this "pollution" while preventing me from having to type `A.Red`/`A.Blue` in module B?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes there is.

You can, when defining `t` in `B`, state that it is equal to `A.t` and rewrite the list of its constructors:

```
module B = struct
  type t = A.t = Red | Blue
  let f = function
    | Red -> 1
    | Blue -> 0
end
```

The typechecker will verify that the definition is the exact same as in `A` so even if you modify your type definition in A you'll be reminded to change it in `B` as well (yes, you type twice the same thing but it's a simple dumb copy/paste).

Comment: I knew I had seen it somewhere! I had tried `type t : A.t = Red | Blue` and some variants, but I missed the right one.

Comment: Don't hesitate to check the OCaml manual, the part II is a bit scary at first but contains really interesting and useful informations.

Answer (score 3):

With OCaml 4.02.x and later you can use ppx_import (https://github.com/ocaml-ppx/ppx_import).

`a.ml`

```
type t = A | B
```

`b.ml`

```
(* This gives a similar result to PatJ's answer *)
type a_t = [%import: A.t]
let foo = function
  | A -> 0
  | B -> 1
```

It's less explicit than PatJ's suggested approach.  The ppx may be simpler if you're working with a large type definition or if `A.t` is changing frequently during development.

A downside of the ppx approach is that you can't `[%import]` types from within the same source file.  The imported type needs to be defined in a separate compilation unit.

Comment: That's some cool work, I'll have to get a look into it. Can it copy the definition from the mli? That would be a nice plus to my workflow.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @PatJ is a good one. Here is another approach that is sometimes useful: you can define three modules, one containing only your type, and then `A` and `B`. Open the first module in `A` and `B`.

Comment: Well, this is also working though it is not always perfect for code readability when used a lot.